# Incorrect hypothesis counter

Tags: numbering, theorems

The hypotheses counter seems to work incorrectly. All hypotheses are numbered with a 1. What exactly am I doing wrong? 
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{uncertainty}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{svo}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{uncertaintytype}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}


\begin{uncertainty}
Predictions are
\end{uncertainty}


Subjects with different social value orientations 

\begin{svo}
Subjects  
\end{svo}

Depending on

\begin{uncertaintytype}
Subjects predictions 
\end{uncertaintytype}


\end{document}
```

I appreciate every comment!

Comment: To Latex they are not `Hypthesis` but `uncertainty`, `svo`, `uncertaintytype`. Why wouldn't he number them differently? Now if you want those three different types of “theorem like environments” to share a counter you have to tell Latex. How? [Documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) page 2: **3 Numbering modifications**.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve by having *three separate environments* -- `uncertainty`, `svo`, and `uncertaintype` -- that (i) are all labelled the same by LaTeX, viz., `Hypothesis`, and (ii) are supposed to share the same internal counter. Why not define a *single* environment, say via `\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}`?

Comment: Beware of ambiguous wording. I came here, because the title made me think you are searching for a tex implementation that will count your incorrect hypothesis :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want your three types of theorem to share the same counter you have to use:

```
\newtheorem{uncertainty}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{svo}[uncertainty]{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{uncertaintytype}[uncertainty]{Hypothesis}
```

Note the optional argument that contains the counter `uncertainty`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{uncertainty}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{svo}[uncertainty]{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{uncertaintytype}[uncertainty]{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}


\begin{uncertainty}
Predictions are
\end{uncertainty}


Subjects with different social value orientations

\begin{svo}
Subjects
\end{svo}

Depending on

\begin{uncertaintytype}
Subjects predictions
\end{uncertaintytype}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

To explain how it works, the definition

```
\newtheorem{uncertainty}{Hypothesis}
```

creates a new theorem type called `uncertainty` and `uncertainty` is also the counter used by the environment itself.

When instead you declare

```
\newtheorem{svo}[uncertainty]{Hypothesis}
```

you are creating a new theorem type called `svo` but the counter used by the `svo` environment is `uncertainty`.

`Hypothesis` is just the name printed by LaTeX when you use such an environment.

Also note that, if you don't need different formatting for different theorems, you can define just one, as in the following example, which gives the same result as the above one.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}


\begin{hypothesis}
Predictions are
\end{hypothesis}


Subjects with different social value orientations

\begin{hypothesis}
Subjects
\end{hypothesis}

Depending on

\begin{hypothesis}
Subjects predictions
\end{hypothesis}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would remark that they are not `Hypothesis` to Latex. That's just the name Latex prints.